# How to reverse audio with pyaudio

Tags: python, audio, reverse, pyaudio

I've been tinkering around with [pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) for a while now, trying to reverse a simple wave file with no success.

In (my) theory I would only have to iterate from end to beginning through the file with every callback of pyaudio (1024 frames) fetch the audio data from the according index in the file, reverse the resulting string and play it.

Here is my code (only pyaudio callback and file handling, the rest is untouched from the example code):

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import time
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)


index = 40*1024
wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
wf.setpos(index)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()


def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global index
    data = wf.readframes(frame_count)
    data = data[::-1]
    index-=1024
    wf.setpos(index)

    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)


stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
wf.close()

p.terminate()
```

I know this will crash when it reaches the file beginning, but it should play 40 × 1024 frames of reversed audio...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file you want reversed is small enough to fit in memory, your best bet would be loading it entirely and reversing the data, then streaming it:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

wavefile_name = 'wavefile.wav'
wf = wave.open(wavefile_name, 'rb')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format =
                p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = wf.getnchannels(),
                rate = wf.getframerate(),
                output = True)

full_data = []
data = wf.readframes(1024)

while data:    
    full_data.append(data)
    data = wf.readframes(1024)

data = ''.join(full_data)[::-1]

for i in range(0, len(data), 1024):
    stream.write(data[i:i+1024])
```

However, if the file is too big to fit in memory, you'll need some way of reading the file backwards and feed into the sound system. That's an entirely different problem, because it involves some low level I/O programming to handle the backward reading.

---

Edit: after seeing your full code, I don't see any errors. The code runs properly in my computer, only to fail at the ending of the playback. However, you can do two things. First, you can go to the end of the wavefile to play the entire sound backwards, using this:

```
wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
index = wf.getnframes() - 1024
wf.setpos(index)
```

Second, you have to modify the callback so it doesn't fail when the seek head goes beyond the beginning of the file:

```
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global index
    data = wf.readframes(frame_count)
    data = data[::-1]
    index-=1024
    if index < 0:
        return (data, pyaudio.paAbort)
    else:
        wf.setpos(max(index,0))
        return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)
```

Other than that, it works pretty ok.

Comment: first of all thanks, ill try your code in the coming days!

isn't the method i use to set the pos via wf.setpos(index) basically reverse file reading (decreasing index)? 

and after reading my 1024 frames i reverse them via [::-1]. 

i still can't get my head around what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I could not try your code because it was missing some parts. For instance, I don't know where that callback was being used. Could you paste the full code to check it out? Theoretically what you're doing could work. However I don't think it would be too efficient. Anyway, just post your full code and we'll see.

Comment: Just expanded my answer.

Comment: Maybe. I tried with a sample wav file from the internet and got no problem. Have you tried with a different file?

Comment: Yes i did. still no success. Also tried Windows machine, same result. strange thing is if i write it to a file it sounds perfectly fine.

Comment: There must be an issue with your portaudio installation. If writing the result to a file works properly, then the problem is in the playback, and the code is ok, so there must be a problem with your setup. Could you try with a live cd of some popular distribution?

Comment: Ok i found the issue: at least for me pyaudio used interleaved int16 as datatype. If i now unpacked the string via struct.unpack i had proper data to work with and your [::-1] worked perfectly fine! thanks