# How do I reverse audio using pyaudio?

Tags: python, audio, reverse, pyaudio

i have been messing around in pyaudio for quite a while now and i am wondering how i can reverse an audio, or play it backwards. This is what i have so far, but when i call the function, nothing really happens.
I got this error while running the program.
[This is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMg4d.png)

```html
import pyaudio
import wave

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()


def ReverseAudio(audio):
    audio = wave.open(audio)
    stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(audio.getsampwidth()), channels = audio.getnchannels(), rate = audio.getframerate(),output = True)
    full_data = []
    data = audio.readframes(1024)

    while data:    
        full_data.append(data)
        data = audio.readframes(1024)

    data = ''.join(full_data)[::-1]

    for i in range(0, len(data), 1024):
        stream.write(data[i:i+1024])
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to do this? I have checked other similar questions but none of them seemed to work for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you sure there isn't some keyword argument that deals with this? like `reverse=True`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse audio with pyaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962413/how-to-reverse-audio-with-pyaudio)

Comment: No, i don't think there is a reverse keyword argument like that. BuddyBoblll I've seen that question and tried implementing it in my own function, but no luck.

Comment: I'm not well versed in this, but why are you using a string to reverse your audio? Doesn't `data = full_data[::-1]` work? What about `list(reversed(full_data))`?

Comment: @K.CI when i tried that before it showed this error, TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'.

Comment: I looked more into this, and got it to work with `data = b''.join(full_data)[::-1]`. Still, I tested with a sample was file I had, and the output wasn't exactly reversed. It sounded distorted only.